# ext4js - placing a textfield next to a checkboxfield

Tags: forms, extjs, checkbox

I'm new to using ext4js and web app dev in general.

I have a form, and in that form, I want a checkbox and right next to it is a textfield. I changed the layout type of the form from vbox to column and I set the width of the checkbox and textfield so that they'll both be in one line. So far, that worked great for me.

However, when I duplicated the checkbox and textfield, the result changed. The duplicated checkbox and textfield were on different lines and they were centered.

Here is my code:

```
{
                xtype: 'form',
                itemId: 'spousework',
                maxWidth: 500,
                width: 75,
                layout: 'column',
                bodyBorder: true,
                bodyPadding: 10,
                bodyStyle: 'border-right-style: solid;',
                frameHeader: false,
                header: false,
                title: 'My Form',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'displayfield',
                        itemId: 'userNameField2',
                        margin: '10 0 10 0',
                        maxWidth: 700,
                        minWidth: 700,
                        width: 700,
                        defaultAlign: 'center',
                        fieldLabel: 'Spouse\'s Work',
                        hideLabel: true,
                        labelWidth: 0,
                        value: 'SPOUSE\'S WORK',
                        fieldStyle: 'color: #007AA3; text-align: left; font-weight: bold;'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                        maxHeight: 20,
                        fieldLabel: 'Spouse\'s Employer',
                        labelWidth: 120,
                        boxLabel: ''
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        margin: '0 0 0 10',
                        maxHeight: 20,
                        width: 300,
                        fieldLabel: '',
                        labelWidth: 120
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                        maxHeight: 20,
                        fieldLabel: 'Spouse\'s Employer',
                        labelWidth: 120,
                        boxLabel: ''
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        margin: '0 0 0 10',
                        maxHeight: 20,
                        width: 300,
                        fieldLabel: '',
                        labelWidth: 120
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Can anyone help? How do you properly line up items in succeeding rows using a column layout for the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use filedcontainer in your form like below with column layout

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    layout: 'column',
      fieldLabel: 'Spouse\'s Employer',
    items: [
        {
              xtype: 'checkboxfield',
              maxHeight: 20,
              boxLabel: '',
              margin: '0 5 0 0'
        },
        {
              xtype: 'textfield',
         }
    ]}
```